# Formal grammar for Emacs Lisp

Tags: elisp

Where can I find a formal specification (in EBNF, or some other standard notation -- the source code for the "read" function doesn't count!) for the Emacs Lisp grammar?

I'd even be happy with a .y file; unfortunately, emacs's own parser does not use yacc.

Comment: http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/EmacsLisp.html This is the closest to syntax available for elisp I've found. EBNF grammar would be so useful to me as well right now. wonder if you ever solved the problem.

Comment: Nope, sorry -- I gave up on that project. I'm pretty sure @Drew's response below is correct, and that there is no formal definition other than the source code for the lisp reader in emacs itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) grammar for Emacs Lisp at https://github.com/Wilfred/tree-sitter-elisp/blob/4b0e4a3891337514126ec72c7af394c0ff2cf48c/src/grammar.json
This is a machine-readable grammar specification which is then used to generate a C parser.

Comment: In addition, Guile has a standalone implementation of lexer in parser written in Guile Scheme at https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guile.git/tree/module/language/elisp

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is the same as for any lisp language, isn't it? Here is one describing Lisp from the Lisp page in Wikipedia:

```
expression -> atom | list
atom -> number | name | string | operator
list -> '(' expression* ')'
```

Comment: No, this isn't even close. Emacs Lisp has many other types -- character and string literals, vectors, chartables, for a start -- that have special read syntax. I want a grammar that covers it all.